# How to adjust legend height and direction of data display in High charts heatmaps

Tags: highcharts, legend, heatmap

[HEATMAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0oyj.png)

Take a look at the chart attached. I tried to set properties of legend for heatmap but nothing worked. Is there a way I can set this legend height according to chart height. I was able to change heatmap height but not the legend. Also, how can i reverse the legend numbers order in descending order?

this is what I used to display legend when creating chart, but its not showing legend numbers in descending order, neither does it changes the height to cover full map height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set proper `symbolHeight` for legend and disable `reversed` for color-axis.

```
  colorAxis: {
    ...,
    reversed: false
  },

  legend: {
    ...,
    symbolHeight: 280
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2r0Lbt6d/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.symbolHeight